# Returning mulitple responses of data from a database query using php to jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have two select boxes from my html page. Let's say that the first selectbox contains the value of years (e.g 2013, 2014, 2015, etc) where the user could select a value.

For my second selectbox, it must be dependent to the first selectbox and will be populated with the values that matches the year using database query in php (i.e .. WHERE year='$year') from my first selectbox something like that.

Now, I want to use **JQuery Ajax** to send request into my php script to execute some queries to my database and must return all the data coming from the result of the query as:

**selectPeriod.php**

```
$rci_date = $_POST['r_date1'];  // year selected from my form

$s1 = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT issue_date FROM issue_details WHERE 
                account_type='SPHERE' AND
                issue_type = 'ci' AND
                year(issue_date) = year('$rci_date') ORDER BY issue_date DESC ");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($s1)) {
    $db_issueDate = $row['issue_date'];  // return this data
}
```

In my jquery, this should accept the data from my php which is the result of the query and re-populate my second selectbox with this values. Like on this way but this is not what I want because the query is on my html page and is static only without jquery and has no user interaction to my first selectbox:

```
<select name="mds-trust-date" id="mds-trust-date">
<option value="">Select by period</option>
    <?php 
        $s1 = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT issue_date FROM issue_details
                           WHERE account_type='MDS-TRUST' 
                           AND issue_type = 'ci' AND
                           year(issue_date) = year('$db_currentDate') 
                           ORDER BY issue_date DESC");

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($s1)) {
            $db_issueDate = $row['issue_date'];
            echo '<option value=' . $db_issueDate . '>' . $db_issueDate . '</option>';
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

I tried this code for my jquery ajax but there's something wrong with this:

```
var r_date = $("#rci_date").val();  // get value from selectbox1

   // Value to pass
   var dataString =  'r_date1='+ r_date;

   $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         dataType: 'json',
         url: "functions/ajaxSelect-period.php",
         data: dataString,
         cache: false,
         success: function(response){
            alert(response.a);  // just a confirmation, not repopulating second selectbox
         }
    });
```

And in my php, I did something like this.

```
<?php
    // query to database
    ...

    $array = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($s1)) {
        $array[] = $row['issue_date'];
    }

   // response
   echo json_encode($array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
?>
```

But that has no response back to jquery. Please help me correct my code and also how can I set to re-populate my second selectbox using the data responded from my jquery. Im a new bee to jquery. Really need a help here. Thanks.

Comment: can you wrap your javascript code into one function? and call that function from your page from browser console? and when you POST `data:` should be array not string

Comment: do you have any solution or a better way of passing the data back to my jquery then populuate my second selectbox with that data? If you have, please show me how. Thanks.

Comment: What do you getting in alert there: `alert(response.a);` ?

Comment: nothing. Just a confirmation. How can I populate this data into my second selectbox? Please correct my code. Thanks